# Loop through list, match word call description from list

Tags: c#, list, loops, streamreader

I am having a problem constructing a loop WHICH will COMPARE a VAR(userSelection)  against the name ITEMS in my LIST(Listings). The goal is that if userSelection MATCHES name, getDescription will Console.WriteLine the GetDefinition and display the definition of the word in the list matched. Most of my code is working, and i've been working on this assignment for a week.

I'm very much a newb, please assume I know nothing. All help is appreciated. I think this would be a while loop, but i've played with all the loops now and am lost and confused. I'm a newb, please use small words and be as detailed as you can afford to be. It's greatly appreciated. Thank you.

My C# Program:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using System.Threading.Tasks;// Needed for Streaming...
using System.IO;// Needed for Streaming...

namespace a090___StreamReader_DictionarySearch
{
class Program
{
    private const String FILE_NAME = "dictionary.txt";//establish text file instance

    public void Play()
    {
        do
        {
            DisplayTitle();

            List<Listing> items = LoadListings();//create a list of WordDef objects

            Console.Write(string.Join(" | ", items.Select(x => x.GetName()))); //Console.Write("\b \b");// Backspace would also of worked


            DisplayText("\n\nPlease enter a word from the selections about to see it's definition");// Nice use of PROMPT
            String userSelection = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();//Capture input

            //loop through all of the listings, and compare each one to userSelection
            //Then once it equals print definition

            bool found = false;

            foreach (Listing item in items)
            {
                if (userSelection == item.GetName())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("You selected: " + userSelection +
                                "\nWhich Means: " + item.GetDefinition());
                    found = true;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (!found)
            { Console.WriteLine("I'm sorry, I don't have a match for that."); }

        } while (PlayAgain());

        Salutation();
    }

    //ToolBox -- my program specific tools
    public List<Listing> LoadListings()//load entries display as list
    {
        StreamReader fileIn = new StreamReader(FILE_NAME);
        List<Listing> entry = new List<Listing>();

        //loop through every line of the file
        while (!fileIn.EndOfStream)
        {
            String line = fileIn.ReadLine();
            String[] pieces = line.Split(':');

            if (pieces.Length < 1) continue;//error handling - set to length of text items

            Listing myListing = new Listing(pieces[0], pieces[1]);
            entry.Add(myListing);
        }
        fileIn.Close(); return entry;
    }




    //MaxBox -- my useful tools
    public void DisplayText(String StringNameIs)
    { Console.WriteLine(StringNameIs); }//Where are we?

    public Boolean PlayAgain()
    {
        Console.Write("\n\nDo you select again? (y)es or (n)o: ");
        String command = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();

        if (command == "y" || command == "yes") return true;
        return false;
    }

    public void Salutation()
    { Console.Clear(); Console.WriteLine("Ti Do - oh - oh Ti Do -- So Do!"); } //The last line from the 'do-re-mi' song from the Sound of Music

    public void DisplayTitle()
    { Console.Clear(); Console.WriteLine(">>>-- A Dictionary of Sounds --<<< \n"); } //Announce Our Program  



    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Program DictionaryLookup = new Program();
        DictionaryLookup.Play();
        Console.Read();
    }
}
}
```

My Class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;


namespace a090___StreamReader_DictionarySearch
{
class Listing
{
    private String name;
    private String definition;

    public Listing(String name, String definition)
    { this.name = name; 
      this.definition = definition;}

    public String GetName()       {return name;}
    public String GetDefinition() {return definition; }
}
}
```

My Text File

```
Doe: a deer, a female deer
Ray: a drop of golden sun
Me: a name I call myself
Far: a long, long way to run
Sew: a needle pulling thread
La: a note to follow Sew
```

Tea: a drink with jam and bread

Comment: if i did that, how would you know that the problem doens't come from one of the other aspects that I might of cut out?

Comment: Understood, thank you. Will try to keep that in mind (It helps to understand - and i thought for this one i ought to show name space as i was using the Streamer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is untested, but should work, using your existing code.

Assuming each "name" (doe, ray, etc) only occurs once (which they do), then you can use Linq's "[SingleOrDefault](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.singleordefault%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)", which will return `null` if no match is found.

```
var selection = items.SingleOrDefault(x => x.GetName() == userSelection);

if (selection == null)
    Console.WriteLine("I'm sorry, I don't have a match for that.");
else
    Console.WriteLine("You selected: " + userSelection +
                      "\nWhich Means: " + selection.GetDefinition());
```

To ignore case during comparison, try modifying the above:

```
... items.SingleOrDefault(x => String.Compare(x.GetName(), userSelection, true));
```

There are a number of other things you could change here, but perhaps it won't matter for your assignment. For example, I'd eliminate the private variables in your `Listing` class and change the public "get" methods into properties:

```
public String Name { get; private set; }
public String Definition { get; private set; }
```

Comment: I tried this, but it always returned answer not found: if (items.Select(x => x.GetName()).Contains(userSelection)){var selection = items.Single(x => x.GetName() == userSelection); Console.WriteLine ("You selected: " + userSelection + "\nWhich Means: " + selection.GetDefinition()); } else { Console.WriteLine("I'm sorry, I don't have a match for that."); }

Comment: Looking at the example above, I realized that adding '.ToLower()' made it work. So after i tried stepping though (the instructions on how to do it for express did confuse me and i don't know that i did it right - i'm on a mac running visual studio). I added '.ToLower() to both spots where 'x.GetName()' is mentioned. So I THINK that the issue was comparison of vars with different cases - i was typiing in Sentence case, turning it to lower but the list was still in title case. Doing this made it work. Was that the correct thing to do? Thanks for the learning experience -very much appreciated

Comment: There's wasted overhead in selecting the names (`GetName()`) in the LINQ query and then checking `Contains` and then selecting `Single`. The entire query could be: `items.SingleOrDefault(x => x.GetName() == userSelection)` and then check if the result is `Null`

Comment: What is a LINQ Query? This conversation is the first i've heard of it. Likewise i have not/was not aware of the Compare option. I'm super newb, bit i'm trying not to be. Thanks for all the info and direction.

Comment: LINQ sounds very interesting. I look forward to delving into it in the future. Right now I plan to stay to the tried and true path of mastering loops and methods and arrays and then on to classes, et al.

Answer (score 1):

Substitute the code

```
while (true)
            {
                if (userSelection == name)
                {Console.WriteLine("You selected: " + Listing.userSelection() +
                                "\nWhich Means: " + Listing.items.GetDefinition());}
            }
           else { Console.WriteLine("I'm sorry, I don't have a match for that."); }
```

with this

```
        bool found = false;

        foreach (Listing item in items)
        {
            if (userSelection == item.GetName().ToLower())
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You selected: " + userSelection +
                            "\nWhich Means: " + item.GetDefinition());
                found = true;
                break;
            }
        }


        if (!found)
        { Console.WriteLine("I'm sorry, I don't have a match for that."); }
```

I have use the [foreach](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ttw7t8t6.aspx) statement; with this statement you can iterate all items of your collection.

Inside the foreach loop I check if the element Name is equal with the user input, if match I set a bool variable indicating element found.

After the loop if element not found print the message.

NB Obviously this code can be written more concisely with LINQ.

Comment: I tried implimenting this solution, and it was very nice in that it had no errors. But it always returned the !found answer. I tried testing with Doe and doe, both times the response returned was !found. i think that i ma doing something wrong - I Have updated my code to reflect how i tried to implement your solution Max.

Comment: I have updated the code. I has added ToLower() inside foreach this is because userSelection are "lowered". I suggest to remove ToLower() to both place.